# x:Bind does not work on button_click, works fine in MainPage()

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am newbie, so I am not sure whats wrong with my code. x:Bind works fine in MainPage() method but does not work in button_click event.

In button_click event only second RichTextBox is populated, but in MainPage() method both of RichTextBoxes are populated. I wont to be able to bind on button_click event and not in MainPage() method.

Thanks

Citati cit;

```
    public MainPage()
    {
       // DateTime dat = DateTime.Now;


        this.InitializeComponent();
       // cit = new Citati();
       // int dan = dat.DayOfYear;
       // cit.Citiranje(dan);
       // stpCitat.DataContext = cit;

       //Works for both RichTextBoxes


    }



    private void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dat = DateTime.Now;
        cit = new Citati();
        int dan = dat.DayOfYear;
        cit.Citiranje(dan);
        stpCitat.DataContext = cit;

        //Works only for second RichTextBox


    }

    <StackPanel x:Name="stpCitat">
                <RichTextBlock  x:Name="rtbFirst" >
                    <Paragraph   Margin="50,0,0,0" FontSize="21.333"  >
                        <Run Text="{x:Bind cit.Citat}" Foreground="#FFE02323"></Run>
                    </Paragraph>                        
                    <Paragraph Margin="200,0,0,0">
                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{x:Bind cit.Wiki, Mode=OneWay}" >
                            <Run Text="{x:Bind cit.Slikar}" >
                            </Run>
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBlock>


                <RichTextBlock  x:Name="rtbSecond" >
                    <Paragraph  Margin="50,0,0,0" FontSize="21.333"  >
                        <Run Text="{Binding Citat}"></Run>
                    </Paragraph>                       
                    <Paragraph Margin="200,0,0,0">                           
                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Wiki}" >
                            <Run Text="{Binding Slikar}" >                                    
                            </Run>
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBlock>
                <Button x:Name="btnPopulate" Click="btnPopulate_Click">  
            </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't work because of these two reasons:

1. I'm pretty sure that your `cir` is not a dependency property, nor a `INotifyPropertyChanged` property. The second box is updated because you assign your new `cin` to the `DataContext` which is a dependency property.
2. `x:Bind` default mode is `OneTime`, so if the property or the data context changes, the binding won't be updated.

So, in order to make this code to work, you need to do the following:

1. Make a dependency property that will contain an instance of `Citati`.
2. Bind your properties with `Mode=OneWay`.

The code below will help you:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CinProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register("Cin", typeof(Citati),
     typeof(MainPage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

public Citati Cin
{
    get { return (Citati)GetValue(CinProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CinProperty, value); }
}

private void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dat = DateTime.Now;
    var cit = new Citati();
    int dan = dat.DayOfYear;
    cit.Citiranje(dan);

    stpCitat.DataContext = cit;
    Cit = cit;
}
```

And the markup:

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="rtbFirst" >
    <Paragraph Margin="50,0,0,0" FontSize="21.333"  >
        <Run Text="{x:Bind Cit.Citat, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="#FFE02323"/>
    </Paragraph>                        
    <Paragraph Margin="200,0,0,0">
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{x:Bind cit.Wiki, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <Run Text="{x:Bind Cit.Slikar, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Although I do not understand when to use x:Bind and when Binding :)

Comment: @Toni0123 They are mostly interchangeable, but `x:Bind` is faster, consumes less memory and statically compiled.